# jquery bind keypress not working in android tab

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I got an issue in my android tab my script won't work.

```
jQuery('.letters-field').bind('keypress', function(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        console.log(charCode);
        if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 122))
            return false;
        return true;

    });
```

my script will not allow numbers to be input in a input field, it will only allows letter. It works in other devices but not all in android tab.. any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found key press highly unpredictable particularly with certain keys not triggering the event.  I would personally switch to keyup or keydown. I can't say I experienced this Type of issue with these two alternatives.

```
jQuery('.letters-field').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i tried to replaced it by keyup and keydown but my script that allows letters only wont work

Comment: like I replaced it to be like `jQuery('.letters-field').bind('keydown', function(evt) { ..` but the `return false` or `return true` in my code seems not working

Comment: I've edited my response to include an example piece of code. Does this work for you?